# How long should I expect an Xbox One controller to last on two AAs?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I have a play and charge kit for my Xbox One, but it's totally worn out. The mini-USB connection is flimsy and loses contact constantly, and the battery pack won't hold a charge.

I've ordered a new controller and play and charge kit, but am using AA batteries in the interim.

I'm shocked at how quickly they're being drained. I feel like I'm getting maybe 12 hours of play time out of each pair, if that much. On the 360, I could leave a pair of batteries in for probably five times that long.

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my controller. How long should I expect these batteries to last?

Note: I'm currently using Duracell AAs.

Comment: I definitely feel like 12 hours is far too little. I'll do some digging, and post an answer if I find anything.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, there are no credible sources from Microsoft itself. However, other sources do make claims at AA battery lifespans:

[This article](http://www.videogamer.com/news/xbox_one_play_and_charge_battery_pack_lasts_about_30_hours_on_a_single_charge.html) claims that 40+ hours can be achieved from a pair of AA batteries, whereas the **Play & Charge Kit** can give around 30 hours. The source "Computers and Video Games" apparently also backs this up, but the link is broken from the article.

There's definitely something defective with your current controller, I would imagine. The other fact that you're getting consistently low results from multiple pairs of AA batteries also suggests that it is not the fault of the batteries.

Comment: in my experience, using a headset can also drastically reduce the battery life, especially when used with the dongle

Comment: Using cheap batteries will also be detrimental to battery life. I remember buying a set of 24 AA's for my Game Boy Colour. I went through the whole box in 2-3 days, whereas a high-quality set of two lasted over a week.

Answer (score 2):

[Neogaf](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=759677) has people claiming times all over the place, averaging about 10-20 hours, some more, some less. Probably depending on the type of battery used.

In my personal experiences while on battery, both of my controllers would only live for about 15 hours. I also mainly used Duracell.

Comment: With my 360 I mainly used Energizer once my play and charge kit wore out. Maybe Duracells just suck.

Comment: They are probably cheap for a reason, lol.

Comment: @Rapitor Depends on the specific model of Duracel batteries. http://www.batteryshowdown.com/ has a comparison in both low and high drain situations. Duracel is actually the most expensive brand of batteries you can buy relative to how long they last, especially if you buy their Ultra Power line. If you buy their PROCELL line however, they're actually one of the cheapest brands. However, neither battery beats the IKEA batteries when it comes to sheer power per cost.

Answer (score 0):

I bought my X-Box One back on 2016's Black Friday. Installed a pair of Duracell Quantum's into it, that night. As of this typing on April 17th is when the system finally stated that the batteries are low. Now, I don't use the system on a daily basis. Still, not bad.

Answer (score 0):

Not only are battery brands are different, even battery types are different.

If you are using 'heavy duty' batteries for low drain devices, they actually last shorter than regular batteries.

'Heavy duty' are designed for high drain devices like a cameras flash.  The battery is built differently so more power can be drawn, at the cost of maximum capacity.

Comment: This is interesting. Does the Xbox One controller qualify as a high drain device?

Answer (score 0):

The default Mitsubishi Alkeline battery lasted about a week [(5-7) hour gaming a day] , and Sony Alkeline battery lasts about the same. Cost of each is around 1£ & there is no mAh rating given for them.
Recently I purchaged 4 "Energizer" 1400mAh rechargeable Hybrid Nickel 1.2V battery with charger and they are giving me 2-3 days backup.
N.B: Played most of the games without vibration.

Answer (score -1):

It depeds on the brand of battery and how often you play, but they should last about 2-6 weeks